# Reusing the same variable

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Is there a method to set a dim variable to be reused within the same **fs fo** and **x**. Or do I have to make a unique variable for each time I run the code on the page?

```
<%
itemnum = 1
dim fs,fo,x

fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/images"))

...
%>
```

next section...

```
<%
itemnum = 1
dim fs,fo,x

fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/videos"))

...
%>
```

Comment: This is not ASP.NET but classic ASP.

Comment: Wrap it in a function an use local variables.

Comment: @Diodeus can you provide an example on how to do this? I'm not an asp coder, I'm just tweaking some existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to dim once at the top of your page, you can then re-use it as many times as you like (no need to re-dim / recreate the fso object as long as your code is withing the same scope (page / set of includes)) - even if you go in and out of asp blocks.

Example (all in one asp file):

```
<%
'#### Declare objects and initialise FSO (only has to be done once per request)
dim fs,fo,x 
set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
%>
bla bla bla
<%
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/images")) 
'Do something with the images folder
%>
bla bla bla
<%
set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("/videos")) 
'Do something with the videos folder
%>
bla bla bla
<%
'#### Cleanup
set fo = Nothing
set fs = Nothing
%>
```